# How can I make a clean install of windows 8 if I did an In-place upgrade?

Tags: installation, windows-8

I am in the process of installing windows 8 using the upgrade assistant. At this very moment, it is downloading the files, and after it finishes, I think it will ask me to make an in-place upgrade or to make a clean install by creating media.

I plan to choose the in place upgrade, but if I choose that, will I have the option to create an ISO file later?.

Or is it a better idea to choose "create media" before installing? If I do that, will I still be able to keep all my stuff? Or does "create media" imply a mandatory clean install?

I know most time a clean install is a better option, but I first do want to make an in-place upgrade, and I want is to have the option of making a clean install if something doesn't work properly.

In another words, how can I make a clean install of windows 8 AFTER I already installed it via an in-place upgrade using the upgrade assistant?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/493363/if-i-buy-the-windows-8-pro-upgrade-can-i-do-multiple-fresh-installs

Comment: When you buy Windows 8 you always get a license key. You can always re-download and enter the key. The trick is whether or not the key will work for whatever new scenario you use for the 2nd install. For example, OEM vs. upgrade keys, etc.

Comment: Matthew. thanks ! but now i have a question. Besides that restart and refresh options, can i make a bootable win 8 pro iso within my installation? Or where do i get one? @Mufasa: I am planning to upgrade ANOTHER computer, getting another upgrade key, but i don't want to download the whole file again from that computer. what's my best option? If i choose "create media" instead of "install now", will that media (bootable iso) will still give me the option to keep everything in whatever machine i use it? (having separate upgrade licences of course).

Comment: @DiegoDD - When you installed Windows 8 you were given that chance.  Your limited to the `reset` and `refresh` options at this point.

Comment: (Not sure if this has already been mentioned) Upgrade by creating media will keep whatever you selected in the earlier Apps/Files/Nothing step.

Answer (score 2):

You will actually be able to install it clean FROM your windows 8 installation.

Once you have installed Windows 8, if you choose to do a clean install, do the following:

- Open the charms menu
- Select "Settings"
- At the bottom, select "Change PC settings"
- In this screen choose "General"
- Scroll down to "Remove everything and reinstall Windows"
- Follow the prompts

This will do the same thing as installing from a disk.

*Remember to back up files first!*

Comment: excellent. yes, I've just found that windows 8 now has this two options, reset and refresh. They will be lifesavers if something goes wrong =) . For more people interested, here's a link: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-refresh-or-reset-your-windows-8-pc-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when the download finishes, you'll be prompted with how you want to proceed - either install now with the download as an executible or to create an iso file.
Then when running either of those (now or via iso burnt media), as part of the install, you'll get a few options if you want to do an upgrade or clean install (like a traditional windows install - specifing the install location to an existing windows partition is an upgrade, using the advanced disk option menu to delete the partition and pick the unused space is a clean install).
Once you have built a DVD install disk from the install, you can use that to upgrade other pcs, but you'll need another new key for each upgrade.

Also, the download is based on your current pc's bitness. For example, if you have windows 7 32bit, the download will be win8 32bits. There is no download option for 32/64 bits.

Comment: Great! That is just what i wanted. And excellent to mention that the iso will be the same 'bits' as the current installed windows. I haven't think about it because i only need 64 bit versions, but its good to know, thanks!